# Negative and Zero Log Values in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to plot multiple overlaying charts with X Axis Time and Y axis should toggle between Linear and Log Scale. I am not able to represent my charts appropriately for log scale even after using d3.scale.log().clamp(true).domain([]).range([]).nice()

Below is the code which I am using to map data points to Y axis

```
_initScaleYMap = function() {
    const chart = this.$root().datum();
    const data = chart.getDataSets() || [];
    const dataSets = chart.getDataSets().filter((ds) => ds.getValueAxisId());
    this.scaleYMap(new Map());
    const dataSetsGroupedByValueAxisId = _.groupBy(dataSets, (dataSet) => dataSet.getValueAxisId());
    Object.entries(dataSetsGroupedByValueAxisId).forEach(([valueAxisId, matchedDataSets]) => {
        data.forEach((d) => {
            const chartValueAxis = chart._getValueAxisById(valueAxisId);
            if (!chartValueAxis) {
                throw `Value axis '${valueAxisId} '`;
            }
            const min = chartValueAxis.getMin();
            const max = chartValueAxis.getMax();
            const domain = (Number.isFinite(min) && Number.isFinite(max) && !this.forceArea()) ? [min, max] : getYDomain(chart, matchedDataSets);
            if (!d.getShowLog()) {
                this.scaleYMap().set(valueAxisId,
                    d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain(domain)
                        .range([this.height() - this.margin().top - this.margin().bottom, 0])
            );
            } else {
                this.scaleYMap().set(valueAxisId,
                d3.scale.log().domain(domain).range([this.height() - this.margin().top - this.margin().bottom, 1]).nice()
            );
            }
        });
    });
    return this;
};
```

I am attaching the before and after photos, before being the linear scale for y and after being the Log scale

[On Linear Scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOloW.png)

[On Log Scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Y4T.png)

Comment: can you post the full code, or a link to the full version of your chart?

Comment: Hi, I can give you the specific information you need. But posting full code will not be possible.